# Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration to return MAC and IP adress in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a function that returns the MAC and IP addresses from the local network card with the use of "Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration" in a PowerShell function, but it's not returning anything.

```
function test{
          Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to filter down the results to just return adapters that have an IP address assigned (`where {$_.IPAddress -ne $null}`).  Then, optionally, use select to just get the two properties you want (`select MACAddress, IPAddress`).

```
function test{
    return Get-CimInstance win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.IPAddress -ne $null} | select MACAddress, IPAddress
}
```

This is going to return an object, not a string, so to access the properties individually you would do something like the following:

```
$Config = test
$Config.MACAddress
$Config.IPAddress
```

If you have more than one adapter with an IP address, you'll get an array of objects, and you'll need to loop through them, or use a different WHERE filter to further limit the results.